# como resolver el siguiente error: The sample encountered an error: TypeError: FormRecognizerClient is not a constructor**?

Tags: javascript

```javascript
const {
  FormRecognizerClient,
  AzureKeyCredential
} = require("@azure/ai-form-recognizer");

const fs = require("fs");
async function main() {
  const endpoint = "https://proyectomauriciovargastudela.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
  const apiKey = "****************************";
  const modelId = "4a474b41-5635-4b95-a60f-fe751f8e9a2b";
  const path = "Factura Formato corrido.pdf";

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);

  const client = new FormRecognizerClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));
  const poller = await client.beginRecognizeCustomForms(modelId, readStream, {
    contentType: "application/pdf",
    onProgress: (state) => {
      console.log(`status: ${state.status}`);
    }
  });
  const forms = await poller.pollUntilDone();

  console.log("Forms:");
  for (const form of forms || []) {
    console.log(`${form.formType}, page range: ${form.pageRange}`);
    console.log("Pages:");
    for (const page of form.pages || []) {
      console.log(`Page number: ${page.pageNumber}`);
      console.log("Tables");
      for (const table of page.tables || []) {
        for (const cell of table.cells) {
          console.log(`cell (${cell.rowIndex},${cell.columnIndex}) ${cell.text}`);
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("Fields:");
    for (const fieldName in form.fields) {
      // each field is of type FormField
      const field = form.fields[fieldName];
      console.log(
        `Field ${fieldName} has value '${field.value}' with a confidence score of ${field.confidence}`
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change version of you library to `3.2.0` in your package.json.

i.e. `"@azure/ai-form-recognizer": "3.2.0"` and do `npm i`, it should be resolved after that.

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Tanto la pregunta como las respuestas deben ir en el idioma del sitio.